WPF Dynamic Data Grid's Thumb position changed when row and column definition is added to selected dynamic grid
Requirement:
Our requirement is to draw an empty Grid(table with rows and columns) on top of a tables present in the image and for a single image there may be multiple grids. All the grids should be adjustable and we can add row separator and column separator on mouse button click in the grid. The grids, thumbs and rowcolumn definitions are created from code behind
Problem:
If column or row definition is created the Grid's Thumb position changes and it moves to first row first column instead of remaining static in the outer grid. The top, left, right and bottom thumb's position is changed. Can you please help us on this issue.
XAML:
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="Gray" MouseDown="MainGrid_MouseDown" MouseMove="MainGrid_MouseMove" MouseUp="MainGrid_MouseUp">
<Image x:Name="imgDisplay" Source="{Binding ImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Stretch="None"/>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Cursor="Hand">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF086B69" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    <Button Name="btnAddGrid" Content="Grid" Width="30" Margin="5" Click="AddAdjustableBox_Click"/>
    <Button Name="btnRowSeperator" Content="Row" Width="30" Margin="5" Click="btnRowSeperator_Click"/>
    <Button Name="btnColumnSeperator" Content="Col" Width="30" Margin="5" Click="btnColumnSeperator_Click"/>

C Sharp Code:
    public partial class TableDesignerUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private Point startPoint;
        private Rectangle selectionRectangle;
        private Border resizeBorder;
        private bool isResizing = false;
        private bool isDragging = false;
        private string resizeDirection;
        private bool _columnSeperator;
        private bool _rowSeperator;
        private bool gridGenerator;
        private Grid selectedGrid;
        private Dictionary<Grid, GridData> gridDataMap = new Dictionary<Grid, GridData>();
        private List<Border> selectedCells = new List<Border>();
        private List<Border> gridBorders = new List<Border>();
        private Border activeBorder = null;
        private bool isSelecting = false;
        private bool isDeselecting = false;
        private Border initialCell = null;

        public TableDesignerUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        private void MainGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridGenerator)
            {
                startPoint = e.GetPosition(MainGrid);

                double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
                double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
                Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

                if (startPoint.X < imagePosition.X || startPoint.X > imagePosition.X + imageWidth ||
                    startPoint.Y < imagePosition.Y || startPoint.Y > imagePosition.Y + imageHeight)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot draw outside the boundaries of the image.", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    return;
                }

                selectionRectangle = new Rectangle
                {
                    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                    StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection { 2 },
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Width = 0,
                    Height = 0,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = new Thickness(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, 0, 0)
                };

                MainGrid.Children.Add(selectionRectangle);
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.OriginalSource is Border border && gridBorders.Contains(border))
                {
                    activeBorder = border;
                    SelectGrid(activeBorder.Child as Grid);
                    return;
                }
                else if (e.OriginalSource is Grid grid && grid != MainGrid)
                {
                    SelectGrid(grid);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void MainGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectionRectangle == null || isResizing || isDragging)
                return;

            var currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MainGrid);

            double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
            double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
            Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

            currentPoint.X = Math.Max(imagePosition.X, Math.Min(currentPoint.X, imagePosition.X + imageWidth));
            currentPoint.Y = Math.Max(imagePosition.Y, Math.Min(currentPoint.Y, imagePosition.Y + imageHeight));

            var minX = Math.Min(startPoint.X, currentPoint.X);
            var minY = Math.Min(startPoint.Y, currentPoint.Y);

            var width = Math.Abs(currentPoint.X - startPoint.X);
            var height = Math.Abs(currentPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);

            selectionRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(minX, minY, 0, 0);
            selectionRectangle.Width = width;
            selectionRectangle.Height = height;
        }

        private void MainGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectionRectangle != null && !isResizing && !isDragging)
            {
                var currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MainGrid);

                double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
                double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
                Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

                currentPoint.X = Math.Max(imagePosition.X, Math.Min(currentPoint.X, imagePosition.X + imageWidth));
                currentPoint.Y = Math.Max(imagePosition.Y, Math.Min(currentPoint.Y, imagePosition.Y + imageHeight));

                var minX = Math.Min(startPoint.X, currentPoint.X);
                var minY = Math.Min(startPoint.Y, currentPoint.Y);

                var width = Math.Abs(currentPoint.X - startPoint.X);
                var height = Math.Abs(currentPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);

                MainGrid.Children.Remove(selectionRectangle);

                var border = new Border
                {
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height,
                    BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                    Margin = new Thickness(minX, minY, 0, 0),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
                };

                var grid = new Grid
                {
                    Background = Brushes.LightBlue,
                    Opacity = 0.3,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                };

                AddResizeThumbs(grid);

                grid.MouseLeftButtonDown += Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown;
                border.Child = grid;
                MainGrid.Children.Add(border);
                grid.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                SelectGrid(grid);
                selectionRectangle = null;

                gridBorders.Add(border);
                activeBorder = border;
                gridDataMap[grid] = new GridData(); // Initialize GridData for the new grid
            }
        }

        private void SelectGrid(Grid grid)
        {
            if (grid == null)
                return;

            selectedGrid = grid;

            selectedGrid.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
            selectedGrid.Opacity = 0.5;

            foreach (var border in gridBorders)
            {
                if (border.Child != selectedGrid)
                {
                    (border.Child as Grid).Background = Brushes.Gray;
                    (border.Child as Grid).Opacity = 0.3;
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddResizeThumbs(Grid container)
        {
            AddResizeThumb(container, Cursors.SizeWE, HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment.Stretch, "Right", 0, 0);
            AddResizeThumb(container, Cursors.SizeNS, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment.Bottom, "Bottom", 0, 0);
            AddResizeThumb(container, Cursors.SizeWE, HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment.Stretch, "Left", 0, 0);
            AddResizeThumb(container, Cursors.SizeNS, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment.Top, "Top", 0, 0);
            AddDraggingThumb(container, 0, 0);
        }

        private void AddResizeThumb(Grid container, Cursor cursor, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment, string direction, double marginLeft, double marginTop)
        {
            var thumb = new Thumb
            {
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10,
                Opacity = 1,
                Background = Brushes.White,
                HorizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment,
                VerticalAlignment = verticalAlignment,
                Cursor = cursor,
                Tag = direction,
                Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0)
            };

            thumb.DragStarted += (s, e) =>
            {
                resizeBorder = (Border)container.Parent;
                activeBorder = resizeBorder;
                isResizing = true;
                resizeDirection = (string)thumb.Tag;
                MainGrid.Children.Remove(activeBorder);
                MainGrid.Children.Add(activeBorder);
            };

            thumb.DragDelta += Thumb_DragDelta;
            thumb.DragCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                isResizing = false;
                resizeDirection = null;
            };

            container.Children.Add(thumb);
        }

        private void AddDraggingThumb(Grid container, double marginLeft, double marginTop)
        {
            var thumb = new Thumb
            {
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10,
                Opacity = 1,
                Background = Brushes.Red,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll,
                Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0)
            };

            thumb.DragStarted += (s, e) =>
            {
                resizeBorder = (Border)container.Parent;
                activeBorder = resizeBorder;
                isDragging = true;
                MainGrid.Children.Remove(activeBorder);
                MainGrid.Children.Add(activeBorder);
            };

            thumb.DragDelta += Thumb_DragMove;
            thumb.DragCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                isDragging = false;
            };

            container.Children.Add(thumb);
        }

        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (resizeBorder == null || !isResizing)
                return;

            double newWidth, newHeight, newLeft, newTop;

            double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
            double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
            Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

            switch (resizeDirection)
            {
                case "Right":
                    newWidth = resizeBorder.Width + e.HorizontalChange;
                    if (newWidth > 0 && resizeBorder.Margin.Left + newWidth <= imagePosition.X + imageWidth)
                        resizeBorder.Width = newWidth;
                    break;

                case "Bottom":
                    newHeight = resizeBorder.Height + e.VerticalChange;
                    if (newHeight > 0 && resizeBorder.Margin.Top + newHeight <= imagePosition.Y + imageHeight)
                        resizeBorder.Height = newHeight;
                    break;

                case "Left":
                    newWidth = resizeBorder.Width - e.HorizontalChange;
                    newLeft = resizeBorder.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange;
                    if (newWidth > 0 && newLeft >= imagePosition.X)
                    {
                        resizeBorder.Width = newWidth;
                        resizeBorder.Margin = new Thickness(newLeft, resizeBorder.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
                    }
                    break;

                case "Top":
                    newHeight = resizeBorder.Height - e.VerticalChange;
                    newTop = resizeBorder.Margin.Top + e.VerticalChange;
                    if (newHeight > 0 && newTop >= imagePosition.Y)
                    {
                        resizeBorder.Height = newHeight;
                        resizeBorder.Margin = new Thickness(resizeBorder.Margin.Left, newTop, 0, 0);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            AdjustGridCells();
        }

        private void Thumb_DragMove(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (resizeBorder == null || !isDragging)
                return;

            double newLeft = resizeBorder.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange;
            double newTop = resizeBorder.Margin.Top + e.VerticalChange;

            double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
            double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
            Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

            if (newLeft >= imagePosition.X && newTop >= imagePosition.Y &&
                newLeft + resizeBorder.Width <= imagePosition.X + imageWidth &&
                newTop + resizeBorder.Height <= imagePosition.Y + imageHeight)
            {
                resizeBorder.Margin = new Thickness(newLeft, newTop, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point clickPosition = e.GetPosition(selectedGrid);

            if (_rowSeperator && !isDragging)
            {
                if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.Y))
                {
                    gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Add(clickPosition.Y);
                    gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Sort();
                }
                UpdateGrid();
            }
            else if (_columnSeperator && !isDragging)
            {
                if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.X))
                {
                    gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Add(clickPosition.X);
                    gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Sort();
                }
                UpdateGrid();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateGrid()
        {
            if (selectedGrid == null)
                return;

            selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

            double previousY = 0;
            foreach (var separator in gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators)
            {
                selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(separator - previousY, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
                previousY = separator;
            }
            selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(selectedGrid.ActualHeight - previousY, GridUnitType.Pixel) });

            double previousX = 0;
            foreach (var separator in gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators)
            {
                selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(separator - previousX, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
                previousX = separator;
            }
            selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(selectedGrid.ActualWidth - previousX, GridUnitType.Pixel) });

            for (int row = 0; row < selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; column++)
                {
                    AddGridCell(selectedGrid, row, column);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AdjustGridCells()
        {
            if (selectedGrid == null)
                return;

            foreach (var cell in selectedGrid.Children.OfType<Border>())
            {
                var row = Grid.GetRow(cell);
                var column = Grid.GetColumn(cell);

                cell.Width = selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions[column].Width.Value;
                cell.Height = selectedGrid.RowDefinitions[row].Height.Value;
            }
        }

        private void AddGridCell(Grid grid, int row, int column)
        {
            var cellBorder = new Border
            {
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5),
                Background = Brushes.Transparent
            };

            Grid.SetRow(cellBorder, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(cellBorder, column);
            cellBorder.MouseLeftButtonDown += CellBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            cellBorder.MouseMove += CellBorder_MouseMove;
            cellBorder.MouseLeftButtonUp += CellBorder_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            AddCellResizeThumbs(cellBorder); // Add this line to add thumbs to each cell

            grid.Children.Add(cellBorder);
        }

Output:
Before Adding Separator: The Thumb works as expected

After Adding Separators: The thumb moves to different position

After Adding the UpdateThumbArrangement - (Resizing Grid isn't working and The thumb moves to cell borders instead of grid border)

Output Now:


Hmm, there are no Thumbs in your code? And the logic that locates the Thumbs is also missing. Difficult to understand how everything relates. The Grid can show grid lines: Grid.ShowGridLines = true.

At least from the image we can tell that the box that the Thumb elements are aligned to is perfectly placed to fill the first cell. Maybe that helps.

@BionicCode - I have added the full code. The thumb is not for the cells it's for the grid height and width adjustment. The thumb moves to first cell after creating rowdefinition in updategrid method

Hi @BionicCode - Thanks for correcting the issue. Now the thumb isn't moving it's still stays in the grid that is fine but I am not able to adjust the size of the grid. I didn't get the resize cursor if I hove the mouse on thumb. I have added the image

The problem is that you don't rearrange the Thumb elements.
The point is that by default, child elements of the Grid are placed into the first cell. Their respective Grid.Row and Grid.Column values are 0. This is fine if the Grid does not contain any cells. But as soon you define cells by adding RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition layout elements to the Grid you have to explicitly arrange the children so that they are positioned in the proper cells.
In your case you simply want all Thumb elements to remain in the first cell but make them span across all cells and rows (to make them behave like there are no cells - like in the initial state) by setting Grid.RowSpan to the number of rows and Grid.ColumnSpan to the number of columns:
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (!isDragging)
  {
    return;
  }

  Point clickPosition = e.GetPosition(selectedGrid);

  if (_rowSeperator)
  {
    if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.Y))
    {
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Add(clickPosition.Y);
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Sort();
    }
  }
  else if (_columnSeperator)
  {
    if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.X))
    {
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Add(clickPosition.X);
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Sort();
    }
  }

  // You should pull the UpdateGrid() call out of the if-else blocks 
  // to eliminate duplicate code
  UpdateGrid(); 

  // After you have added RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions you have to 
  // rearrange the Thumb elements to make them span across their parent Grid
  UpdateThumbArrangement();
}

private void UpdateThumbArrangement()
{
  int rowCount = gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Count + 1;
  int columnCount = gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Count + 1;
  IEnumerable<Thumb> thumbs = selectedGrid.Children.OfType<Thumb>();
  foreach (Thumb thumb in thumbs)
  {
    Grid.SetRowSpan(thumb, rowCount);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(thumb, columnCount);
  }
}


After providing more context, the new fixes should be as follows:
Fix Thumb positioning in first Grid cell
UpdateThumbArrangement has changed the signature to accept the hosting Grid as an argument. UpdateThumbArrangement should be genearlly called whenever you add Thumb elements to the root Grid.
private void UpdateThumbArrangement(Grid thumbContainer)
{
  int rowCount = thumbContainer.RowDefinitions.Count;
  int columnCount = thumbContainer.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
  IEnumerable<Thumb> thumbs = thumbContainer.Children.OfType<Thumb>();
  foreach (Thumb thumb in thumbs)
  {
    Grid.SetRowSpan(thumb, rowCount);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(thumb, columnCount);
  }
}

UpdateThumbArrangement is now called from LoadGridState and Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown. You must generally call the new UpdateThumbArrangement´ method whenever you add Thumbekements to the rootGridand whenever you change the cell size of the rootGrid. And whenever you change the size of the root Gridyou must also recalculate the cell sizes. You can use the newRedistributeCellSpacemethod from the next section down below.   With "root Grid" I mean the outerGrid that holds the grid resize Thumb elements.
public void LoadGridState(string filePath)
{
  if (!File.Exists(filePath)) return;

  var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
  var grids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GridModel>>(json);

  gridBorders.Clear();
  gridDataMap.Clear();

  foreach (var gridModel in grids)
  {
    var border = new Border
    {
      Width = gridModel.Width,
      Height = gridModel.Height,
      BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
      BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
      Margin = new Thickness(gridModel.Left, gridModel.Top, 0, 0),
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
    };

    var grid = new Grid
    {
      Background = Brushes.LightBlue,
      Opacity = 0.3,
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
    };

    foreach (var columnDefinition in gridModel.ColumnDefinitions)
    {
      grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(columnDefinition) });
    }

    foreach (var rowDefinition in gridModel.RowDefinitions)
    {
      grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(rowDefinition) });
    }

    foreach (var cell in gridModel.Cells)
    {
      var cellBorder = new Border
      {
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue,
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5),
        Background = Brushes.Transparent,
      };

      Grid.SetRow(cellBorder, cell.Row);
      Grid.SetColumn(cellBorder, cell.Column);

      if (cell.RowSpan > 1)
      {
        Grid.SetRowSpan(cellBorder, cell.RowSpan);
      }

      if (cell.ColumnSpan > 1)
      {
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(cellBorder, cell.ColumnSpan);
      }

      cellBorder.MouseLeftButtonDown += CellBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown;
      cellBorder.MouseMove += CellBorder_MouseMove;
      cellBorder.MouseLeftButtonUp += CellBorder_MouseLeftButtonUp;

      AddCellResizeThumbs(cellBorder);

      grid.Children.Add(cellBorder);
    }

    gridDataMap[grid] = new GridData
    {
      RowSeparators = gridModel.Separators.RowSeparators,
      ColumnSeparators = gridModel.Separators.ColumnSeparators
    };

    AddResizeThumbs(grid);
    UpdateThumbArrangement(grid);

    grid.MouseLeftButtonDown += Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    border.Child = grid;
    MainGrid.Children.Add(border);
    grid.Margin = new Thickness(0);

    gridBorders.Add(border);
    SelectGrid(grid);
  }
}

And Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown now looks as follows (added new UpdateThumbArrangement and refactored). You must apply column and row spans after modifying the cell count. UpdateThumbArrangement does this.
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (isDragging)
  {
    return;
  }

  Point clickPosition = e.GetPosition(selectedGrid);

  if (_rowSeperator)
  {
    if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.Y))
    {
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Add(clickPosition.Y);
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators.Sort();
    }
  }
  else if (_columnSeperator)
  {
    if (!gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Contains(clickPosition.X))
    {
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Add(clickPosition.X);
      gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators.Sort();
    }
  }

  UpdateGrid();
  UpdateThumbArrangement(selectedGrid);
}

Fix resize behavior
Add height and width check to avoid an exeception for negative values. This version uses Math.Max to ensure a value that is greater than or equal to zero.
private void UpdateGrid()
{
  if (selectedGrid == null)
    return;

  selectedGrid.Children.Clear();
  selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
  selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

  double previousY = 0;
  foreach (var separator in gridDataMap[selectedGrid].RowSeparators)
  {
    selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(separator - previousY, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
    previousY = separator;
  }

  // Use Math.Max to avoid negative height values
  selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(Math.Max(0, selectedGrid.ActualHeight - previousY), GridUnitType.Pixel) });

  double previousX = 0;
  foreach (var separator in gridDataMap[selectedGrid].ColumnSeparators)
  {
    selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(separator - previousX, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
    previousX = separator;
  }

  // Use Math.Max to avoid negative width values
  selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(Math.Max(0, selectedGrid.ActualWidth - previousX), GridUnitType.Pixel) });

  for (int row = 0; row < selectedGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; row++)
  {
    for (int column = 0; column < selectedGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; column++)
    {
      AddGridCell(selectedGrid, row, column);
    }
  }

  AddResizeThumbs(selectedGrid);
}

Call the introduced RedistributeCellSpace method after the Border was resized. Also add Math.Max for robustness (to prevent negative values or values less than the minHeight minWidth limits.
private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
  if (resizeBorder == null || !isResizing) return;

  double newLeft, newTop;

  double imageWidth = imgDisplay.ActualWidth;
  double imageHeight = imgDisplay.ActualHeight;
  Point imagePosition = imgDisplay.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), MainGrid);

  // TODO::Define both variables as const fields
  const double minWidth = 10;
  const double minHeight = 10;

  Size oldResizeBorderSize = resizeBorder.RenderSize;
  double newWidth = oldResizeBorderSize.Width;
  double newHeight = oldResizeBorderSize.Height;

  switch (resizeDirection)
  {
    case "Right":
      newWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, resizeBorder.Width + e.HorizontalChange / 2);
      if (newWidth >= minWidth && resizeBorder.Margin.Left + newWidth <= imagePosition.X + imageWidth)
        resizeBorder.Width = newWidth;
      break;

    case "Bottom":
      newHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, resizeBorder.Height + e.VerticalChange / 2);
      if (newHeight >= minHeight && resizeBorder.Margin.Top + newHeight <= imagePosition.Y + imageHeight)
        resizeBorder.Height = newHeight;

      break;

    case "Left":
      newWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, resizeBorder.Width - e.HorizontalChange / 2);
      newLeft = resizeBorder.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange / 2;
      if (newWidth >= minWidth && newLeft >= imagePosition.X)
      {
        resizeBorder.Width = newWidth;
        resizeBorder.Margin = new Thickness(newLeft, resizeBorder.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
      }
      break;

    case "Top":
      newHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, resizeBorder.Height - e.VerticalChange / 2);
      newTop = resizeBorder.Margin.Top + e.VerticalChange / 2;
      if (newHeight >= minHeight && newTop >= imagePosition.Y)
      {
        resizeBorder.Height = newHeight;
        resizeBorder.Margin = new Thickness(resizeBorder.Margin.Left, newTop, 0, 0);
      }
      break;
  }

  // Ensure the last cell and last column remain static
  if (resizeBorder.Child is Grid grid)
  {
    var newResizeBorderSize = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
    RedistributeCellSpace(grid, oldResizeBorderSize, newResizeBorderSize);
    foreach (var child in grid.Children.OfType<Border>())
    {
      if (IsLastCellOrLastColumn(child))
      {
        child. Width = double. Nan;
        child. Height = double. Nan;
      }
    }
  }
}

New method added to recalculate the cell size after the Grid has been resized. This will actually allow the Thumb elements to be properly arranged. This is necessary because of the fixed cell sizes.
private static void RedistributeCellSpace(Grid grid, Size oldSize, Size newSize)
{
  bool hasHeightChanged = oldSize.Height != newSize.Height;
  if (hasHeightChanged)
  {
    double heightRatio = newSize.Height / oldSize.Height;
    foreach (RowDefinition rowDefinition in grid.RowDefinitions.Where(rowDefinition => rowDefinition.Height.IsAbsolute))
    {
      double heightChange = rowDefinition.Height.Value * heightRatio;
      rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(heightChange);
    }
  }

  bool hasWidthChanged = oldSize.Width != newSize.Width;
  if (hasWidthChanged)
  {
    double widthRatio = newSize.Width  / oldSize.Width ;
    foreach (ColumnDefinition columnDefinition in grid.ColumnDefinitions.Where(columnDefinition => columnDefinition.Width.IsAbsolute))
    {
      double heightChange = columnDefinition.Width.Value * widthRatio;
      columnDefinition.Width = new GridLength(heightChange);
    }
  }
}

That's it. But you must also check your cell resize behavior. It's broken too.

Thanks for correcting the issue. Now the thumb isn't moving it's still stays in the grid that is fine but I am not able to adjust the size of the grid. I didn't get the resize cursor

I have updated the example. There was a mistake in the refactored Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown  method. I also improved the if-statements.

Are you saying that the resize behavior was working correctly before my suggested changes? I doubt it.

https://github.com/VigneshJayaraman05/WpfTableDesigner.git.     I have added the full source code in GitHub. Please find the link

Thank you. I can't open the zip. Why don't you create a proper repository so that I can directly review the source code or even clone it? This would be a great help for both of us.

However, I think I had already identified the issue, I guess. Just hadn't time to post anything. Are the cells of the grid always of the same size (Grid space i s distributed evenly) or can each have a different size.?

Hi @BionicCode - Please use this github repo
https://github.com/VigneshJayaraman05/WPF-Grid.git

Thank you. I will look into it tomorrow. The fix is simple. I will then post he changed source files.

The image is missing.

Please find the below image link
https://github.com/VigneshJayaraman05/WPF-Grid/blob/main/demo1.jpg

Hi @BionicCode - Thanks for spending time on this and sharing the code. The grid resizing is working now but the Bottom thumb and right side thumb moves outside/disappears I adjust the individual cells thumb. Can you please help me how to make the grid's last column and row static.

I don't know how you want the cells to behave. What do you mean by last row and column static?

You must redistribute the cell and row space. Just rework your calculations

I mean the tables border

Resizing the complete grid works now right? Cell resizing needs to be fixed by fixing the calculations. You can try to exclude the last column and row form you algorithm. For example, if your grid has 3 cells, then you only set the width and height of the first two rows and columns. The last column and row are set to *. This will make the last cell always fill the remaining space.. Then write the cell calculation from scratch. The first resizes because your calculations are wrong. Is you give a column more width you have to take the same amount from the adjacent column (redistribution).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
